# Laravel 5. How to grab posts by category and not by type

Tags: laravel-5

On the project i'm dealing there are three main components type, category and post.

Example: We have 3 types (news, photo, video) each type has its own categories.
So **news** has 3 categories **news1**, **news2**, **new3** and each of them has its own posts.

Now i can access the type with mydomain.com/news and of course now i receive all the post (not separated on categories)

I want to show the posts by category, so when i access mydomain.com/news i will foreach categories and below them the associated posts.

```
$categories = Categories::byType($t)->get();

$lastItems = Posts::select('posts.*')
        ->leftJoin('categories', function($leftJoin){
            $leftJoin->on('categories.id', '=', 'posts.category_id');
        })
        ->approve('yes')
        ->latest("published_at")
        ->get();
```

So i have something like this on my controller, it is separated with categories but on each category is show all the posts that are associated with news type and not by categories.

Comment: This way you're getting all the posts which are in all the categories from the selected type, correct? So each post is related to a category so you'll be able to display them by category.

Comment: Yes, but how to do it ?

Comment: `Posts::with('category')->approve('yes')->latest("published_at") ->get()->groupBy('category_id')->all();` Key of the array is category id